# PHP / Bash: Creating PPK out of OpenSSH Key with passphrase

Tags: php, openssl, putty, private-key

I would like to create a php script that creates keys for ssh-authentication.
I've started with a

```
exec("ssh-keygen -b 1024 -t dsa -N *pwd* -f *path-to-file* -q");
```

to create the private and public-key-pair. No problem till here ;)

Now I've to convert the OpenSSL-Key to the ppk-format of PuTTY (in the cmd, not in the GUI). If anyone have an Idea on how to manage that, please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were working with RSA keys you could do this (requires [phpseclib](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/)):

```
<?php
include('Crypt/RSA.php');

$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
$rsa->setPassword('password');
$rsa->loadKey('...');

//$rsa->setPassword(); // clear the password if there was one
echo $rsa->getPrivateKey(CRYPT_RSA_PRIVATE_FORMAT_PUTTY);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have not specified, what OS you run at. On *nix, you can use PuTTYgen (from PuTTY):

```
puttygen openssl-key -o mykey.ppk
```

For details see: https://manpages.debian.org/stable/putty-tools/puttygen.1.en.html

On Windows, PuTTYgen is a GUI application only. Though, you can use WinSCP, it has [PuTTYgen-compatible command-line interface](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline#keygen):

```
winscp.com /keygen openssl-key -o mykey.ppk
```