# use ppk file to connect to sftp in PHP

Tags: php, sftp, phpseclib

I am having trouble connecting to an SFTP server using a .ppk file that are provided.

I have tried this ppk file in Filezilla and it works.
According to one of the comments in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28256655/connect-to-sftp-using-php-and-private-key) it is better to use phpseclib but i didnt find any instructions on how to download files from SFTP using a ppk file. Any directions or suggestions?

Here is the code I'm not sure if that will help or not.

```
include('Net/SSH2.php');
include('Crypt/RSA.php');
include('Net/SFTP.php');


DEFINE('SERVER','sample.sftp.com');
DEFINE('USER','sampleUserName');
DEFINE('KEY','sample_key_22733_priv.ppk');

$sftp = new Net_SFTP(SERVER);

//I guess this password is useless here
//and i will have to use my ppk file here but i don't know how

if (!$sftp->login(USER, 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

var_dump($sftp->nlist());
```

Comment: check this question  [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16132200/php-bash-creating-ppk-out-of-openssh-key-with-passphrase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16132200/php-bash-creating-ppk-out-of-openssh-key-with-passphrase)

Comment: @mdamia I dont get it. It seems all the instructions stopped after getting the private key. What do i do from there?

Answer (score 3):

phpseclib works perfectly fine with PPK files, assuming they're RSA keys and not DSA keys. Just initialize a `Crypt_RSA` object and then call `loadKey(file_get_contents('path/to/key.ppk'))` on that object.

To download files do `$sftp->get('/path/to/filename.ext')`.

Here's your orig code modified to include all this:

```
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');
include('Crypt/RSA.php');
include('Net/SFTP.php');


DEFINE('SERVER','sample.sftp.com');
DEFINE('USER','sampleUserName');
DEFINE('KEY','sample_key_22733_priv.ppk');

$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
$rsa->loadKey(file_get_contents(KEY));

$sftp = new Net_SFTP(SERVER);

//I guess this password is useless here
//and i will have to use my ppk file here but i don't know how

if (!$sftp->login(USER, $rsa)) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

echo $sftp->get('/path/to/filename.ext');
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** 
As @neubert confirmed,  PPK files are supported but you do need to make sure they are RSA as I explained, but you do not need them in OpenSSH format

---

Convert your PPK to an <s>OpenSSH</s> RSA key.  You can convert this using the PuTTYgen executable: http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html

Once you have it in an RSA key, you can use this with phpseclib: http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/auth.html#rsakey

Comment: Doesn't phpseclib support PuTTY itself?

Comment: I don't think so.  PPK files are putty-specific, it isn't a standard key format.  Try it and see.  Either way, you have to make sure it is an RSA key.

Comment: $rsa->getPrivateKey(CRYPT_RSA_PRIVATE_FORMAT_PUTTY);?

Comment: Okay, so maybe they do support it but like I said, you still need to make sure it is an RSA key and not DSA.

Comment: What to do after i have the connection? how do i list files on the server? or download them? I have tried $ssh->exec('ls -a') and it returned false

Comment: Their site has some pretty good examples on it.   This is beyond the scope of the original question.  The example I gave you was SSH, but you can establish SFTP in a similar manner.